# Java - Reading a text file from a web page sometimes doesn't update correctly

Tags: java

I'm reading a remote text file from a site which changes fairly often, using this code:

```
URL url = new URL(sourceAddress);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    retrievedText += line+lineBreak;
}
reader.close();
```

Now my issue is when I read this text, it doesn't change even after the source text file changes (it is not still uploading). Even application restarts do not return the "latest" text.

Oddly enough, if I have the aforementioned text file open in a browser and hit refresh, the next time my Java application polls the file it will retrieve the latest content - even if the application was closed entirely.

This leads me to believe it may be some caching issue, but I'm completely stumped about how to get around it.

Any help and or advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to disable caches:

```
URL url = new URL(sourceAddress); 
urlConn = url.openConnection();  
urlConn.setUseCaches(false);  
InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader( url.openStream());  
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(stream); 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a parameter like "&_=" + System.currentTimeMillis() in order to avoid caching (if it happens somewhere in the middle, e.g. on a proxy-server).